# Why can there be more than one maximal ideal of a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I just started learning about ideals and I'm really confused about this.

I read that a ring can have two maximal ideals, the example that was given was $(2)$,$(3)$ for the ring $\mathbb Z$.

But on the other hand, it says that the sum of ideals is also an ideal? Wouldn't then the set $(2)+(3)$ also be an ideal of the ring $\mathbb Z$ that contains both $(2)$ and $(3)$? Why are then $(2)$ and $(3)$ maximal?

Comment: $(2)+(3)=\Bbb Z$

Comment: Thank you so much. Does that mean that the sum of any two maximal ideals of the ring is the ring itself?

Comment: Yes, the sum of two distinct maximal ideals is the whole ring

Comment: Thank you again

Comment: And to the title question: the reason that we can have more than one maximal ideal is, that they need not be contained in each other. What are exactly the maximal ideals of the ring $\Bbb Z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because $(2)+(3)=\Bbb Z$, which is *not* an proper ideal. And this is true because $1=3-2$, and therefore, for each $n\in\Bbb Z$, $n=3n-2n$.

Comment: I can't see why $\mathbb{Z}$ is not an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$. Not a proper one, but surely an ideal?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path I am sorry; I forgot the word “proper”.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be an arbitrary ring, and $\mathfrak{A}=\{ \mathfrak{a}\subset A : \mathfrak{a} \text{ is ideal and } \mathfrak{a} \neq A\}$ be the set of all proper ideals of $A$. One can see quite easily that $\subset$ defines a partial-order on $\mathfrak{A}$. A *maximal* ideal is now a maximal element of the partially ordered set ($\mathfrak{A}$,$\subset$). I.e. an ideal $\mathfrak{m}\subset A$ is maximal iff $\mathfrak{m}\neq A$ and if for all ideals $\mathfrak{n}\subset $A with $\mathfrak{n}\neq A$ it holds that $\mathfrak{n}\supset\mathfrak{m}$ implies that $\mathfrak{n}=\mathfrak{m}$. Now let $\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{n}\subset A$ be two *distinct* maximal ideals then $\mathfrak{m}+\mathfrak{n}=A$, because evidently $\mathfrak{m}+\mathfrak{n}\supset \mathfrak{m}$ hence if $\mathfrak{m}+\mathfrak{n}\neq A$ then $\mathfrak{m}+\mathfrak{n}=\mathfrak{m}$. This means that for all $n\in \mathfrak{n}$ there exist $m,m'\in \mathfrak{m}$ s.t. $m+n=m'$ thus $n=m'-m\in \mathfrak{m}$ thus $\mathfrak{m}\supset \mathfrak{n}$ a contradiction. Thus, we must have $\mathfrak{m}+\mathfrak{n}=A$.